# How does salesforce notify the solution provider in the error message "Your Solution Provider has been notified"?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, error, exception

We are an ISV partner and sometimes our clients get the following error when working with our package. We want to know where the notification goes and how we are notified so we can catch the bug without having them inform us.

> Script-thrown exception Error is in expression '{![MethodName]}' in
>   component  in page [PageName] ([PackageName])
>   An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been
>   notified.

Comment: To get the latest info and an appropriate response from Salesforce, I'd recommend you to login to the partner community and ask this question there.

Comment: While creating the packages, Salesforce asks you to SELECT a user for  `notify on error` field. An email is sent to that email address. The details about the email format are given here. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_handling_managed_errors.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [manjit-singh](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4517/manjit-singh) said in comments:

> While creating the packages, Salesforce asks you to SELECT a user for notify on error field. An email is sent to that email address. The details about the email format are given here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_handling_managed_errors.htm&language=en_US